# How to make a responsive polygon shape cards like this using CSS?

Tags: html, css, clip-path

[image: Expected Output]

So far I have tried this, but the border is not showing here. How can I make this card responsive? should I use a media query?

[image: My Design]

Here is my CSS:

```
.shape {
  width: 300px;
  height: 96px;
  position: relative;
}
.shape::before {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 296px;
  height: 92px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  z-index: -10;
}

.shape,
.shape::before {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 61%, 74% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 61%, 74% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}
```

Comment: Your CSS has a syntax error, there's a comma where a closing brace should be. Also add a negative z-index to the :before element to get the text to show.

Comment: @dantheman thanks for your comments,  I have made the changes but the border is not showing.